# Twitter Streaming API - low Input rate in flink/spark application

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twitter, apache-flink

I am working with apache flink and spark and a twitter conntector (flink-connector-twitter_2.12 and spark-streaming-twitter from apache.bahir) to receive real time tweets and predict them through a svm.

**Flink**:

```scala
val streamSource: DataStream[String] = strEnv.addSource(new TwitterSource(properties))
...
```

**Spark**:

```scala
TwitterUtils.createStream(streamingContext, auth)
...
```

however, both applications are running on a cluster using the mentioned APIs.

My problem is the low input rate from twitter.
The spark application has a avg of: 51.98 records/sec which is compared to the real twitter data (6k per second) extremly low.

**Question**: Is there any way to improve the input rate?

I appreciate any help :) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Flink uses the [sample api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/api-reference/get-statuses-sample). This API returns the sample of tweets in real time.It's worth noting that this API is limited, just as all standard non-paid Twitter APIs, the rate limiting is described in detail [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/rate-limiting). The best idea would be to switch to Premium Twitter API which does not have limitations.

Comment: I'd add that the premium API does not currently offer a streaming option so this may not work, BB it a commercial optionloke enterprise might do so.

Comment: It was mentioned here already, but if I recall correctly you may need to keep a budget in mind of anything between 2k and 100k annually for paid API access.